# Sporadic IFRAME 'refused to connect' error with .NET Core Azure Web App

Tags: c#, .net-core, iframe, azure-web-app-service, cross-domain

We have a website [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and an iframe on subdomain.mywebsite.com.

It generally works fine but very, very occasionally the iframe shows 'subdomain.mywebsite.com' refused to connect, like this:

Chrome: "subdomain.mywebsite.com refused to connect"

Firefox: "Firefox Can't Open This Page. To protect your security subdomain.mywebsite.com will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it"

If you refresh the page (in Chrome and FF) then it then works as normal. It's driving me mad as it's so hard to replicate.

The iframe content is an Azure .NET Core Web App. So I'm guessing that something to do with the .NET Core setup/startup.cs?

In Firefox just closing the browser and reopening it generates a one-time error, but refresh, again, makes it work fine. Perhaps some kind of session cookie set by the .NET app that makes it work on the next page load?

In Chrome once you refresh it works if you close the browser and retry, seemingly for days.

I can't replicate this locally so it's quite hard to debug.

Looking for any ideas for pinpointing the cause of this!

**EDIT**
Now seeing this in Console

"chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'https://subdomain.mywebsite.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

If I check response headers at this moment I see:
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

But when I refresh, it works and there is no error. When I check the headers now I see no X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: G'day - Have you set [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive via Content-Security-Policy header by any chance?

Comment: @fuzzy_logic, I don't see anything like this in the headers and I certainly haven't manually added this!

Answer (score 0):

So in my startup.cs I had this in the Configure section:

```cs
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());
```

But had forgotten to add this to the ConfigureServices section:

```cs
services.AddCors();
```

I also added, in my controller this:

```cs
Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

Which I don't think is necessary but I was suspecting something was setting the X-Frame-Options value incorrectly, so this forces it to have no value and so default to allow all.

Now working in Chrome and Firefox all the time.

**EDIT** This hasn't worked, it's back!

**EDIT**
In the end I was still seeing an X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN header on first load in Firefox (it still worked normally on refresh).

The only way I could get this working was by adding this to my ConfigureServices:

```cs
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```

Which supresses any kind of X-Frame-Options being sent, and this seems to work, i.e. Chrome, Edge, Firefox all load the iframe first time now.

The issue I suppose is it would be nice to specify a domain that was allowed with the ALLOW-FROM (as suggested by @PunitSharma-MT below), but that directive is now not-advised see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options - "This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it")

So this means anyone can embed my webapp in an iframe I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have the same problem.
I have tried both adding cors in the service collection as

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins(
                        "https://example.com/",
                        "https://*.example.com/",
                        "https://example.azurewebsites.net/")
                                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });
```

Everything works fine on the azure site, but when imbedding it into test.example.com, I need to hit refresh to show the iframe content.

I tried a bunch of other stuff, but kinda gave up by now ...

I've also ended with adding

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```